# How to provide different shipping methods in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am working on Magento-2.2.4 website.

1. How to show the different availability timings at product detailed page? And
2. How to show those shipping methods at checkout page?

**Description is as follows :**

We are maintaining own warehouse to supply the products from our warehouse to the customers. If the product is available at my warehouse, we will deliver that product within one day. But, if the product is not available at my warehouse, we will bring that from another person's warehouse to our warehouse and sure we will supply to the customer but we have to show that, Item will deliver withing 3days, within 5 days like that.